# How to display user input field when selecting variations on Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I have some variable products with the same characteristics. They are t-shirts and have 3 variations (simple / monogram / full name) so the user can selected what he wants to get printed on the tshirt. However I want when the user selects either the monogram or the full name variation, to display an input text field so he can type in either the monogram or the full name for the personalization.

How can I do that?

I've added the code below in my functions.php file

```
// Display custom fields for variations
function custom_variation_fields($loop, $variation_data, $variation) {
    error_log('Display custom fields for variations');

    $product_ids = array(3671, 444); 

    // Check if $variation is an instance of WC_Product_Variation
    if ($variation instanceof WC_Product_Variation && in_array($variation->get_parent_id(), $product_ids)) {
        // Only show custom fields for specified products

        // For "With Monogram" variation
        woocommerce_wp_text_input(array(
            'id' => '_monogram_field[' . $loop . ']',
            'label' => 'Monogram',
            'placeholder' => 'Enter Monogram',
            'desc_tip' => 'true',
            'description' => 'Enter the monogram for this variation.'
        ));

        // For "Full Name" variation
        woocommerce_wp_text_input(array(
            'id' => '_full_name_field[' . $loop . ']',
            'label' => 'Full Name',
            'placeholder' => 'Enter Full Name',
            'desc_tip' => 'true',
            'description' => 'Enter the full name for this variation.'
        ));
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_variation_options', 'custom_variation_fields', 10, 3);

// Save custom fields for variations
function save_custom_variation_fields($variation_id, $i) {
    error_log('Save custom fields for variations');

    $product_ids = array(3671, 444); 

    if (in_array(wp_get_post_parent_id($variation_id), $product_ids)) {
        // Only save custom fields for specified products

        $monogram = sanitize_text_field($_POST['_monogram_field'][$i]);
        update_post_meta($variation_id, '_monogram_field', $monogram);

        $full_name = sanitize_text_field($_POST['_full_name_field'][$i]);
        update_post_meta($variation_id, '_full_name_field', $full_name);
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'save_custom_variation_fields', 10, 2);

// Display custom fields on the frontend above the "Add to Cart" button
function display_custom_fields() {
    error_log('Display custom fields on the frontend');

    global $product;

    $product_ids = array(3671, 444); 

    if ($product->is_type('variable') && in_array($product->get_id(), $product_ids)) {
        // Output the variation ID as a data attribute for JS to use
        echo '<div id="variation-id" data-variation-id="' . esc_attr($product->get_id()) . '"></div>';

        // Output a placeholder for the custom fields
        echo '<div id="custom-fields-container"></div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: You say *"I've added the code below in my functions.php file"* … So What happen with that code? What is the problem? Note that the function `display_custom_fields()` is not hooked has no effect actually (or you didn't provide the complete code version).

Comment: I think  you'll need to use JavaScript or jQuery alongside your existing PHP code.

Comment: I'm trying to work the Javascript part so I can read the variations id and based on that do the rest. However I'm not quite sure about the PHP part